# Facet streaming expression in solr

Tags: solr, stream, facet

I am new to solr streaming, and wondering how can i use facet streaming expression to get multiple facet counts.

```
facet(                                      
    collection1,
    q="*:*",
    buckets="brand,assortment",
        bucketSorts="count(*) desc",
bucketSizeLimit=1000,
        count(*)
)
```

I have document :

```
Doc1:
 brand: AB
 assortment : TG
 brand : CD
 assortment : TG
```

I expect it to give two buckets one for each field.But the response is like

```
response: [{
   "brand" : "AB"
   "assortment" : "TG"
   "count" : 1
},
   "brand" : "CD"
   "assortment" : "TG"
   "count" : 1
}]

I was expecting :

response :[{
   "brandfacet" : [
  {
   "brand" : "AB"
   "count" : 1},
  {
   "brand" : "CD"
   "count" : 1}
]
"assortmentfacet" : [
  {
   "assortment" : "TG"
   "count" : 2}
}]
```

Comment: The function of the `buckets` parameter is to facet across multiple dimensions, i.e. count the unique set of combinations. Try using multiple facet expressions, then wrap them in `plist()` to have them executed in parallel and returned as a single list (.. and then use whether the key `brand` or `assortment` is present to determine which facet the row belongs to).

Comment: I tried using plist but apparently we are using solr 7.1 which does not support it.

Comment: `list` is the non-parallel version of the same

Comment: May be this is too late to answer but.
Have you try using json.facet api?
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/json-request-api.html